# Django-Taggit in Edit Form

Tags: django, django-taggit

This is a Model Class

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
  (...)
  pasta = TaggableManager(verbose_name=u'Pasta')
```

and a form template (normal :P )

{{form.as_p}}

I'd like to leave everything very clean and usefull.
But result is a list of TaggedItem Object :( :

```
[<TaggedItem: id: 2 tagged with general >, <TaggedItem: id: 3  tagged with outer >]
```

[image]

Instead of something like

```
general, outer
```

How do it fashionably in Django?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give a look at the code in: https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/blob/master/taggit/forms.py. You will find the widget used to render the tags. You can use it to render them correctly.

Example:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager


class Example(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)    
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

forms.py

```
.models import Example
from django import forms
from taggit.forms import TagWidget


class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = ('name', 'tags',)
        widgets = {
            'tags': TagWidget(),
        }
```

I'd recommend you to check this answer too.
[django - django-taggit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359714/django-django-taggit-form)

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue but the solution in this answer has no effect for me. I'm using Django 1.7 and django-taggit==0.12.2. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [django-taggit-autosuggest](https://bitbucket.org/fabian/django-taggit-autosuggest/overview) as it offers better UI to the user.