# Django Taggit rendering tags as object in custom form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-taggit

Duplicate question to [Django-Taggit in Edit Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091940/django-taggit-in-edit-form). However, the answer doesn't work for me.

I'm using Django Taggit in a form. The form is populated by an instance of an object that has Django Taggit enabled.

In my template, the forms tag input field value is set like so:

```
value="{{ form.tags.value|default_if_none:"" }}"
```

This results in a string value in the rough format of:

```
value="[<TaggedItem: foo tagged with bar>]"
```

If I render the form using basic Django form rendering ( i.e. {{form}} ), the tag field value is rendered correctly ( i.e. "tag1, tag2" ). Strangely, this is the opposite to what the poster of [Django-Taggit in Edit Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091940/django-taggit-in-edit-form) was experiencing. For them, {{ form }} wasn't rendering the value correctly, but for me, it is.

Why is there this difference between my form and Django's? How can I make the tag value render correctly in my custom form template?

Comment: Do you have it running online and in a project? Then we could check out links.

Comment: @User It's not online I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that feels hacky but works.

When instantiating the form, modify the initial state for the tags:

```
form = YourModelForm(request.POST or None, instance=your_model_instance, initial={
    'tags' : edit_string_for_tags(your_model_instance.tags.get_query_set())
})
```

`edit_string_for_tags()` and `get_query_set()` are part of Django Taggit.

Note: You'll need to import `edit_string_for_tags()`. i.e. `from taggit.utils import edit_string_for_tags`