# save_m2m 'unicode' object has no attribute 'set'

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-taggit

I'm trying to use taggit in a form, but I'm getting this message:

```
'unicode' object has no attribute 'set'
```

for the method save_m2m.
This is my code.

```
if form.is_valid():
            response = form.save(commit=False)
            #response = super(ReviewForm, self).save(commit=False)
            response.user = user
            response.tag = form.cleaned_data['tag']
            response.product = product
            response.review_text = form.cleaned_data['review_text']
            response.created = time.strftime("%c")
            response.updated = time.strftime("%c")
            response.save()
            form.save_m2m()
```

Full traceback:
Environment:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/kinect-xbox-360/review_submit/

Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'reviews',
 'south',
 'taggit')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:

    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "/Users/filipeferminiano/Documents/django/consumidor/consumidor/reviews/views.py" in single_product
      89.             form.save_m2m()
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_m2m
      96.                 f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/taggit/managers.py" in save_form_data
      125.         getattr(instance, self.name).set(*value)

    Exception Type: AttributeError at /kinect-xbox-360/review_submit/
    Exception Value: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'set'
```

I'm following taggit [docs](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/blob/master/docs/forms.txt):

Comment: Also please post the body of ReviewForm ModelForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very familiar with django-taggit but in ReviewForm try changing

```
tag = forms.CharField( ...
```

to something like

```
tags = TagField()
```

or use

```
  'tags': TagWidget()
```

see [django - django-taggit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359714/django-django-taggit-form) and [Django-Taggit in Edit Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091940/django-taggit-in-edit-form)